# Dynamic allocation of many Boost::histogram objects

Tags: c++, boost, histogram

I need to dynamically create (and later delete) many Boost::histogram objects, each with different numbers of axes and bin boundaries, but I don't think I can create a single one with the make_histogram factory function.  It doesn't return a pointer, so I can't delete the object.   Can anyone provide example code to dynamically allocate a single histogram?

Answer (score 2):

It could be intimidating to look at the code and see all those templates and `auto` return types, I know.

What you can do is to make yourself a couple of handy factories to get a unique (or shared) pointer:

```
#include <boost/histogram.hpp>
#include <memory>
#include <tuple>

template <class Storage, class Axis, class... Axes,
          class = boost::histogram::detail::requires_axis<Axis>>
auto make_unique_histogram_with(Storage&& storage, Axis&& axis,
                                Axes&&... axes) {
  auto a =
      std::make_tuple(std::forward<Axis>(axis), std::forward<Axes>(axes)...);
  using U = boost::histogram::detail::remove_cvref_t<Storage>;
  using S = boost::mp11::mp_if<boost::histogram::detail::is_storage<U>, U,
                               boost::histogram::storage_adaptor<U>>;
  return std::make_unique<boost::histogram::histogram<decltype(a), S>>(
      std::move(a), S(std::forward<Storage>(storage)));
}

template <class Axis, class... Axes,
          class = boost::histogram::detail::requires_axis<Axis>>
auto make_unique_histogram(Axis&& axis, Axes&&... axes) {
  return make_unique_histogram_with(boost::histogram::default_storage(),
                                    std::forward<Axis>(axis),
                                    std::forward<Axes>(axes)...);
}

int main() {
  auto histogram = make_unique_histogram(
      boost::histogram::axis::regular<>(6, -1.0, 2.0, "x"));
  (*histogram)(0.1, boost::histogram::weight(1.0));
}
```

The code was taken from boost/histogram/make_histogram.hpp and slightly modified. In a similar fashion you can rewrite the rest of the helpers.

Reminder: You will need a C++14 compatible compiler.